# How to monitor and get notify which VPS within one node is sending mass emails?

Tags: centos, vps, system-monitoring, warning

How to monitor and get notify which VPS within one node is sending mass emails (spam) ?

Actually I have several nodes with CentoS OS and KVM VPS clients, some of them are sending bulk emails and datacenter keep sending warning that my server will be suspended if thing continue like this.

I need some how to automatically get warnings if one VPS have emails stuck in queue, this way I will immediately send a warning to client and suspend/delete VPS if he continues.

Comment: Do you have access to thos vps? Any existent monitoring system? What type of mail server do you use for VPS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, those VPSs are rented by clients, I don't have legal access but some of them are sending  bulk emails and I need to find out when.